# OpenConnect VPN via NetworkManager: invalid default route, still using local gateway?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm using network-manager-openvpn to connect to my university VPN. The VPN works when I just run `openconnect -u username vpn.host.edu` from the commandline (although it spews a lot of `ip route` error messages).

However, when starting the VPN through the NetworkManager GUI, the resulting routing table is messed up:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.178.1 dev enxXXXXXXXXXXXX
default dev vpn0 proto static scope link metric 50 
default via 192.168.178.1 dev enxXXXXXXXXXXXX proto dhcp metric 20100 
[...]
```

The first entry causes all traffic to still be routed through the local gateway. Consequently, e.g. name resolution with the VPN DNS servers fails and the VPN is unusable. When I remove the first routing table entry with `ip route del default via 192.168.178.1 dev enxXXXXXXXXXXXX`, then everything starts working as intended.

All network settings for the VPN connection are set to "Automatic", so why is the VPN entry not the first default route?

P.S. I know that there are workarounds described in [Network Manager does not set IP4.GATEWAY for OpenVPN connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820393/network-manager-does-not-set-ip4-gateway-for-openvpn-connection?rq=1) and [Network Manager does not set IP4.GATEWAY for OpenVPN connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820393/network-manager-does-not-set-ip4-gateway-for-openvpn-connection?rq=1) - but I would like to fix this without having to run a shell command everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as usual, I found the (more or less) solution 5 minutes after posting the question :-/

It seems like this bug is related: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openconnect/-/issues/33#note_889793

The linked comment suggests using a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` to fix the routes, I'm using this for now.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Hacky workaround bug in NM not setting the default routes.
if [ "$IFACE" = "vpn0" ]; then
  #ip route replace default via 0.0.0.0 dev vpn0
  ip route del default via 192.168.178.1 dev enxXXXXXXXXXXXX
fi
```

I'd still like to see this fixed without hacky scripts, but apparently, it's a known bug.

Comment: To prevent it add default route; you can config using GUI:
Settings > Network >  VPN > Click setting button > Select IPv4 > Check [Use this connection only for resources on its network] (IPv6 the same)